# Return different Dto using same repository method with Nhibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a Web API that request a GET method that can return based in the same parameters different results (Dtos) example:

```
GET - http://localhost/books/searchAll?Detailed=true `
Returns DTO 1 ["Id":1,"Date": 01/01/2014]

GET - http://localhost/books/searchAll?Detailed=false `
Returns DTO 2 ["Id":1]
```

What is the best approach to deal with this situation :

Should I create a http response with one Dto that includes two different list of results :

```
Public Class ResultList
{
   Public List<Dto> DtoList1{get;set;}
   Public List<Dto2> DtoList2{get;set;}
}
```

Or with just one dto list that return a dynamic list

```
Public Class ResultList
{
  Public List<dynamic> DtoList{get;set;}
}
```

Or other solution ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are returning two different resources (or classes or types) I would definitely go for having two different methods but also they would serve two different URLs, let's say for eg. Search and searchDetail.

If you re returning the same resource but one time full and the other partially then I would have one method, use the detail parameter you suggested but I would return the same dto class sometimes with all it's attributes wit values and others only with its minimum attributes with value. After all you are returning a json object which can have dynamic attributes without any problem.

That's what I think.

Comment: Hi, the second option that you refered seems better in my case. But how can I make a dto that will have the same results but with more or less fields ?  I mean fields not values like this :  result 1 : {"id":1} result 2 {"id":1,"type":2}

Comment: @user3511244  well, you could try having a class hierarchy (inheritance) where the base class d have the minimum attributes. Then have only one method returning the base class, possibly the json converter would use the attributes of the specific object you are returning.

Comment: @user3511244 another way to implement what you want would be to have a custom json converter that looks for a parameter which indicates which fields of the returning object will be passed to json response. I have seen such implementation in java using spring and a framework called "yoga". I have no idea if there is a .net version of it, but it seem s it's Wyatt best suits your needs.